# Angular loss in tensorflow doesn't decrease

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, loss-function

Recently I am implementing the "FC4: Fully Convolutional Color Constancy with Confidence-weighted Pooling" paper in tensorflow. In the paper, angular loss is defined as "angular loss = arccos(cosine_distance(vector1, vector2))". However, I tried several ways to implement this loss function but in training they hardly ever decreased. The relevant code is shown as below, any help and suggestions are appreciated.

```
def build_model(self):

    self.learning_rate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    self.input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.batch_size, None, None, 3])
    self.target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [self.batch_size, 3])
    #the shape of result_vec is [self.batch_size, 3]
    self.result_vec = self.build_network(self.input, 'color_net')
    cos_dist = tf.losses.cosine_distance(self.target, self.result_vec, dim=1)
    cos_dist_list,acos_list = tf.unstack(cos_dist), []
    for dist in cos_dist_list:
        acos_list.append(tf.acos(dist)) 
    stack_loss = tf.stack(acos_list)
    self.angular_loss = tf.reduce_mean(stack_loss)
    var_list = tf.trainable_variables()
    self.optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = self.learning_rate)\
                                        .minimize(self.angular_loss, var_list = var_list)
```